# Apache2 php_admin_flag opcache.enable on is ignored

Tags: apache-2.4, virtualhost, php.ini, php7, opcache

I run Apache 2.4.10 with PHP 7.1.17 on my Debian 8.10 server.
When I try to enable opcache in a vhost the changed setting isn't applied.
If I enable opcache globally in the php.ini everything is working as expected.
I also checked that php settings applied in a vhost are (usually) applied after the reload. In my case I set opcache.file_cache which worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems I found my problem:
I already set opcache.enable to 0 in the php.ini.
When I commented the line out, the apache config worked.